# Ckeditor - forcePasteAsPlainText only for a single element/tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

While using Ckeditor, I have defined the `bold` feature as:

```
config.coreStyles_bold =
        {
            element : 'span',
            attributes : { 'style' : 'font-weight:bold' }
        };
```

and I also use `config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;` to make all the text to be pasted as plain text. This works fine, but I need to make the above element to keep its format when it's pasted.

So any bold text should be pasted as bold, while the rest of the text should be pasted as plain text.

Can someone please advise how may I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for this for a while, I managed to find a solution:

In the `config.js` file, I added this line:

```
config.pasteFilter = 'span{*}';
```

which will allow to be pasted only on the `<span>` elements that have set an inline `style`. A more strict rule for this case would be:

```
config.pasteFilter = 'span{font-weight}';
```

I also removed `config.forcePasteAsPlainText = true;` (or it cam be set to `false`)